# Wordpress website - Header working fine in one page but distorts the other pages

Tags: html, css, header, elementor

Elementor Header working fine in First page but it distorts text and other fields when the same header is called on other pages of website. I am new in website designs and html css. Request for a solution.

Tried css , html combinations and bootstrap libraries installed but stoill problem is not resolved